# I need quick start to Java, Apache, and Java web based apps to use JasperReports

Tags: java, apache

Sorry, it is **NOT** duplicated question, just read it please,

I'm totally new to Java world, I'm a .NET developer, and I have a good exprience in ASP.NET.

Now I have a task to make a demo for [JasperReport](http://jasperforge.org/jasperreports), I need **QUICK** start to Java and Java web application on Apache and then I will figure out how to use *JasperReport*.

Thank you very much people,

Comment: if you need to learn the basics of java, you can take this link [Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a PHP dev who tinkers with javascript when neccessary, I was tasked with producing an application using jasper reports, because "java is like javascript, right?". Thankfully, some kind folk have produced an open source utility (.jar) that run jasper reports from the shell/command line.

It's called "RunJasperReports" (). [ttp://code.google.com/p/runjasperreports/](http://code.google.com/p/runjasperreports/)I haven't looked at the latest release but the one I ended up using supports MySQL, PostgreSQL and a couple of other data sources, and shouldn't be too difficult to extend if you can find the right odbc drivers.

Once you have a template up and running (designed in iReport), you can use the language of your choice (assuming shell access) to produce reports by simply running the utility with parameters for the jrxml template path, desired format and database url.

Comment: thanks @supposedJavaGuru, it looks so helpful, I will try the utility ... I hope my lake of Java knowledge will not slow me down!

Answer (score 0):

Both Tomcat (Apache's Java server) and JasperReports come with a wealth of examples. Tomcat also comes with decent documentation (I don't know about the JR documentation, not having used the product recently).
And you've already been pointed to the Java tutorial to learn the basics about the language itself.

Comment: yes, but reading the documentation required lot of time, I need quick start stuff to just run the report, then I can dive in whatever I want later. thank you,